# onLoad detect if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do detection onLoad to see if a radio button is checked. If it is then I want to output some text into a div. Currently it isn't working onLoad and the functionality only works on click.

I'm using local storage to remember if a user has selected certain fields on refresh and this works fine - so whatever radio button was selected before a refresh shows after.

This is the code to change the text onLoad:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var circuitNum = $('input[name="options[numberCircuitsMetre]"]:checked').val();

    if (circuitNum == 'As many as possible per metre') {
     $('#circuit').text('As many as possible per metre');
    }
}
```

See full code:

```js
 // Circuit Select

 // Toggle Metre Question and fill out summary
  $('input[name="options[numberCircuitsMetre]"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="As many as possible per metre"){
      $(".toggleQuestion").hide();
      $('#circuit').text('As many as possible per metre');
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="Custom number"){
      $(".toggleQuestion").show();
    }
  });

 var circuitNum = $('input[name="options[numberCircuitsMetre]"]:checked').val();

 if (circuitNum == 'As many as possible per metre') {
  $('#circuit').text('As many as possible per metre');
 }
 if (circuitNum == 'Custom number') {
  if($('.circuitsNum').val() == ''){
    $('.circuitsValidation').html("<span class='flash'>Please add the number of circuits you want per metre</span>");
    $('.circuitsNum').addClass("errorBorder");
    var errorMessage = 'true';
    } else {
   $('#circuit').text('#circuitsNum'.value || '');
  }
  $(".toggleQuestion").show();
 }
 $("#circuitsNum").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
  $('#circuit').text(this.value || '');
 }).change();
  
   $('#no').click(function() {
  var term = $('#circuitsNum').val();
  $('#circuit').text(term || '');
 });
```

```css
.radio-toggle {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.toggleQuestion {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<!-- No. of Circuit Designs -->
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Do you want as many circuit designs per metre as possible?</label>

                    <div class="radio-toggle">
                    <div class="row collapse radio-shack">

                      <div class="large-6 columns">
                        <div class="radio-margin">
                        <div class="radio-zone">
                          <input type="radio" name="options[numberCircuitsMetre]" id="yes" class="substrate" value="As many as possible per metre" checked="checked" />
                          <div class="check-cover">
                          </div>
                          <div class="check"></div>
                          <label for="yes">
                            <div class="label-head"><strong>Yes</strong></div>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="large-6 columns">
                        <div class="radio-margin">
                        <div class="radio-zone">
                          <input type="radio" name="options[numberCircuitsMetre]" id="no" class="substrate" value="Custom number"/>
                          <div class="check-cover">
                          </div>
                          <div class="check"></div>
                          <label for="no">
                            <div class="label-head"><strong>No</strong></div>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>

                  <div class="toggleQuestion">
                    <label>How many circuit designs per metre would you like?</label>
                   
                    <input type="number" name="options[numberCircuits]" step="any" placeholder="Add the number of circuits per metre..." class="circuitsNum number" id="circuitsNum">
                    <p class="circuitsValidation"></p>
                  </div>

                  </fieldset>
                  
                  
   <div class="summary-row">
        <div class="summary-cell summary-head">
          <strong>No. of circuits:</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="summary-cell">
          <span id="circuit"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/0zzdkb32/44/ I just add this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="options[numberCircuitsMetre]"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == localStorage.getItem('selected')) {
      $(this).click();
      if($(this).val()=="As many as possible per metre"){
          $(".toggleQuestion").hide();
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#circuit').text('As many as possible per metre');
          }, 100);
      }
      if($(this).attr("value")=="Custom number"){
          $(".toggleQuestion").show();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

and add

```
localStorage.setItem('selected', $(this).val());
```

in your click event